# Change property of RiverPod StateNotifier state

Tags: flutter, riverpod

When using StateNotifier with Riverpod, how do we notify the change of state whenever we change any property of the state object?

```
class UserState {
    String name;
    int age;
    bool isActive;
    bool isLoading;

    UserState();
}

class UserStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<UserState> {
    UserStateNotifier() : super(UserStateNotifier());
    
    void setActive() {
        state.isActive = true; // Changing property of state object doesn't refresh UI
        state = state; // Need to do this to force the change of state object
    }

    Future getUserPosts() {
        state.isLoading = true; 
        state = state; 
        
        // await userRepo.getUserPosts();

        state.isLoading = false; 
        state = state; 
    }
}
```

As you can see from the example above, I need to set "state = state" multiple times to force the change of state object to notify changes on the UI. While this approach kind of works, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.. Can someone please help me improve this code?

Just trying to get better with Riverpod :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do it like this

```
void setActive() {
        state = state..isActive = true;
    }
```

if you have an immutable state class with copyWith function do it like this:

```
void setActive(){
    state = state.copyWith(isActive: true);
```

}

Comment: This was the equivalent to setState((){}), exactly what I needed. Thank you!